# How to check if rate limited without invoking actions

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Title; Basically, I want to check if my bot is currently being rate-limited without invoking any actions.

Currently, I know I can do this:

```
async Task<bool> IsRateLimited() {
     try {
         // Assuming I have a channel to send to.
         await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("something"); // Or some only action that can trigger rate limit
         return true;
     } catch (RateLimitedException) {
         return false;
     }
}
```

But the downside is that I would have to invoke an action on the channel/server in order to check if I am rate-limited, which I would want to avoid.

I checked around the documentations for Discord.Net such feature, but there was no such function to do so.

(By the way, there is no actual context to the usage of this.
I am just curious on how one would check if the bot is rate-limited without affecting the server.)

Comment: Well, you keep statistics of how many calls you've done in the past time frame and check if the number exceeds the limits

Comment: Discord has several different rate limits, including per route rate limits. For which particular rate limit are you trying to 'poll' here?